# How do I rearrange the order of Spotlight categories?

Tags: spotlight, system-settings

I believe I used to have the ability to rearrange the search categories shown in Spotlight, but I can't drag to rearrange within System Preferences > Spotlight anymore (El Capitan). Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple removed this feature in El Capitan. I searched deeper in spotlight's plist file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Spotlight.plist
```

But I can't find any way to re order the entries in this version of OS X.

Further Reading:

- [[Help] Reorder results in Spotlight searches](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXElCapitan/comments/3lf3tj/help_reorder_results_in_spotlight_searches/)
- [5 Great New Spotlight Search Tricks in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/03/5-great-spotlight-search-tricks-os-x/)

Comment: Where do I downvote Apple for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to just turn off spotlight suggestions. For me, PDF comes right to the top, followed by my other docs, which is just how I want it.